# What are the neuroscience research findings on the importance of breaks in cognitive function and specifically learning?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology, educational-psychology

When I say breaks I mean breaks between periods of the same course, breaks between two distinct courses, single days of, weekends, couple days of, few days of, longer periods of holidays of duration more than a week and the longest of them summer.

How long can we keep thinking and learning, such that we maximise our thinking and learning? 90 minutes?

What short breaks do we need? 15 minutes?

How many times in a day can we have a 90 minutes period?

How many times per week can we have such a day?

How many times per year can we have such weeks?

Different years have different amounts of studying time in the same school, same year(1st, 2nd, 3rd), and same generation(the different years are close to each other) is this not a problem?

I am a cancer patient since 16, a medical student aiming for radiation oncology and subsidiary MSc&Phd in radiophysics. I am actually autistic but with no mental retardation. So the questions are absolutely necessary as subsidiaries to help me explain myself, why some events seem paradoxical and exactly what information I need. I extensively and thoroughly read ncbi, pubmed and textbooks concerned with my question in hand. A single link I can provide is https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6039789/

Comment: Related: [How long should I work before taking a break?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/3496/7001) and [Effects of quantity and quality of breaks on learning](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/17030/7001).

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg Could I please receive an answer?

Comment: A lot of people use the term "neuroscience" when they actually mean "psychology" - are you really interested in the neuroscience of study breaks (eg, brain scans), or are you just looking to optimize learning?

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I am really interested in neuroscience (brain scans or better yet neurochemisty). Some psychology could be added in the answer as long as it is really well founded (brain scans, neurochemistry etc)